# Why Is My Background Image Not Displaying

Tags: html, css

I have the following css code and I need to display a background image for a page, however nothing is working. I made sure that I'm correctly accessing the path so it's not the problem. Probably there is a flaw in my CSS Code? Sorry Stack Overflow keeps saying my question has too much code and less details but I have described my problem already. So I'm just typing so that I can post may question and get a feedback.

My code is the following:

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
text-decoration: none;
}

body{
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.background{
background: url("./assets/img/rooms/room3.jpg") no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
}

.text, .box{
margin-top: 45vh;
flex: 1;
}

.text{
margin-left: 10%;
font-weight: 300px;
}

.box{
margin-left: 25%;
}

.text h1{
font-size: 70px;
font-weight: 500;
color: purple;
}

.text p{
color: purple;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: 300;
}

.text p a{
font-weight: 700;
color: orange;
}

.form{
box-sizing: border-box;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
width: 250px;
}

input{
margin: 20px 0;
padding: 10px;
border: none;
outline: none;
color: grey;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.username, .password{
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.button{
border: 1px solid purple;
color: purple;
font-size: 18px;
}

.button:hover{
background: white;
color: #;
}
```

Sample HTML:

```
div class="background">
<div class="text">
<h1>Login</h1>
 <p>No Account? <a href="signup.html">Click Here To Sign up</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <form class="form">
                <input type="text" class="username"      placeholder="Username" required>
                <input type="password" class="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                <input type="submit" class="button" value="Login">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you show us the html code? By the way, when we say your question has too much details, we mean that you don't need to show us all of the css rules, just the parts that are relevant to your question.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors. Just a white background

Comment: Code works so sounds like your path to the image is incorrect. I replaced the url with `http://placekitten.com/g/200/300` and it showed up.

Comment: Do you have a link to share? Or right click, inspect element and open the image. Does it show a 404 error? If it does, then your path is not set correctly.

Comment: Right click on your background path in devtools CSS inspector and click "Open in new tab", then you will see if your path is incorrect which it probably is